# redirect to a page on a button click without submitting a form in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, buttonclick

I am trying to redirect my page to a location (`addparty.php?edit=true&id=1`) with a button click. I am using JavaScript for a static value. Here is the code:

Here is my PHP code and JavaScript function.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM party ORDER BY partyName");
echo mysql_error();
while($note = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><label>$note[partyId]</label></td>";
  echo "<td><label>$note[partyName]</label></td>";
  echo "<td><label>$note[partyAddress]</label></td>";
  echo "<td><label>$note[partyBankAcc]</label></td>";
  echo "<td><label>$note[partyBankName]</label></td>";
  echo "<td><label>$note[partyRTGSCode]</label></td>";
  echo "<td><label>$note[partyEmail]</label></td>";
  echo '<td><button name="change" id="change" value="$note[partyId]" 
                    onClick="check();">Edit</button>
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Javascript code:

```
function check()
{
    window.location.href="addparty.php?edit=true&id=1";
}
```

Here I am getting all the values from party table. I want to got to `addparty.php?edit=true&id=$note[partyId]`.If you see the `onClick` event it calls `check()` function. Now my `id=1` is static and it works, but I want that `id=$note[partyId]` (which is unique party id of each party).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the button to this:

```
echo '<td><button name="change" id="change" onClick="check(' . $note['partyId'].');">Edit</button>';
```

Change javascript to this:

```
function check(id)
{
    window.location.href="addparty.php?edit=true&id=" + id;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pitchinnate this works fine. thanks a lot. but only thing is, it also gives me an error "use of undefined constant partyId". any solution for that?

Comment: do you have quotes around partyId like i have in my solution? is there a column named partyId in the database?

Comment: got it...I forgot the quotes. and is there a way to delete that same record by adding a button like this in a while loop?

Comment: Sure you can either use a button with an ajax call or you can redirect to a page to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$note[partyId]` as a parameter to your `check()` -

```
function check(partyId)
{
    window.location.href="addparty.php?edit=true&id="+partyid;
}
```

and

```
echo '<td><button name="change" id="change" onClick="check('.$note['partyId'].');">Edit</button>
```